# How can I make a called cell unique to each worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba, function

I created a UDF that requires the contents of the first non-blank cell above it. I have called the variable for the contents "PriorFootnote". Unfortunately, my UDF records only the contents of the active worksheet as "PriorFootnote" and carries that value through to the UDF when the UDF is placed on other worksheets. Each worksheet should have a unique "PriorFootnote" based on where the first non-blank cell is on that worksheet. In short, my UDF only works on the active worksheet. How can I make my UDF more dynamic?

Here's the problematic code.

```
    With Application.Caller.Parent

        If IsEmpty(Cells(Application.Caller.Row - 1, Application.Caller.Column)) Then

            PriorFootnote = Cells(Application.Caller.Row, Application.Caller.Column).End(xlUp).Value

        Else

            PriorFootnote = Cells(Application.Caller.Row - 1, Application.Caller.Column).Value

        End If

    End With
```

FWIW, this is the entire code:

```
Function Footnote(Optional FootnoteX As Variant)

Dim FootnoteNumArray, FootnoteLetArray, PriorFootnoteUni As Variant
Dim PriorFootnote, OnesChar, TensChar As String
Dim ArrayPos, OnesArrayPos, TensArrayPos, TensCharUni, OnesCharUni As Integer

 FootnoteNumArray = Array(8304, 185, 178, 179, 8308, 8309, 8310, 8311, 8312, 8313)
'FootnoteNumArray = Supercript[(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)]

 FootnoteLetArray = Array(7491, 7495, 7580, 7496, 7497, 7584, 7501, 688, 8305, 690, 7503, 737, 7504, 8319, 7506, 7510, 32, 691, 738, 7511, 7512, 7515, 695, 739, 696, 7611)
'FootnoteLetArray = Supercript[(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, _, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z)]

 Application.Volatile

    If IsMissing(FootnoteX) Then

    '   Get prior footnote

        With Application.Caller.Parent

            If IsEmpty(Cells(Application.Caller.Row - 1, Application.Caller.Column)) Then

                PriorFootnote = Cells(Application.Caller.Row, Application.Caller.Column).End(xlUp).Value

            Else

                PriorFootnote = Cells(Application.Caller.Row - 1, Application.Caller.Column).Value

            End If

        End With

     '  Prior footnote is

        PriorFootnoteUni = Application.Unicode(PriorFootnote)

            'If prior footnote is a number, check its length and convert the footnote Unicode to a number + 1

             If IsNumeric(Application.Match(PriorFootnoteUni, FootnoteNumArray, 0)) Then

                 If Len(PriorFootnote) = 1 Then

                     ArrayPos = Application.Match(PriorFootnoteUni, FootnoteNumArray, 0)
                     FootnoteX = ArrayPos
                     Footnote = FootnoteNumLet(FootnoteX)

                 Else

                     TensChar = VBA.Strings.Left(PriorFootnote, 1)
                     TensCharUni = Application.Unicode(TensChar)
                     TensArrayPos = Application.Match(TensCharUni, FootnoteNumArray, 0)

                     OnesChar = VBA.Strings.Right(PriorFootnote, 1)
                     OnesCharUni = Application.Unicode(OnesChar)
                     OnesArrayPos = Application.Match(OnesCharUni, FootnoteNumArray, 0)

                     FootnoteX = (TensArrayPos - 1) * 10 + OnesArrayPos
                     Footnote = FootnoteNumLet(FootnoteX)

                 End If 'one or two digits

             ElseIf IsNumeric(Application.Match(PriorFootnoteUni, FootnoteLetArray, 0)) Then

                 ArrayPos = Application.Match(PriorFootnoteUni, FootnoteLetArray, 0)
                 Footnote = Application.Unichar(FootnoteLetArray(ArrayPos))

             Else

                 Footnote = Application.Unichar(185)

             End If 'number or letter

    Else

        Footnote = FootnoteNumLet(FootnoteX)

    End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you are using the `With` statement, you are not using it. The `Cells()` statement by itself always returns the value from the Active Sheet.  You must put the period in front of the `Cells()` property as follows:

```
With Application.Caller.Parent

    If IsEmpty(.Cells(Application.Caller.Row - 1, Application.Caller.Column)) Then

        PriorFootnote = .Cells(Application.Caller.Row, Application.Caller.Column).End(xlUp).Value

    Else

        PriorFootnote = .Cells(Application.Caller.Row - 1, Application.Caller.Column).Value

    End If

End With
```

That should get it sorted.

Comment: Details, schmeetails… Thank you! I really appreciate the help.